# Omni Pay - Pin Payments Generic error

Tags: php, omnipay

You know how generic error messages arent much helpfull.

I'm trying to get Omnipay to work with Pin Payments.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Omnipay\CreditCard;
use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;

$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('Pin');


    $gateway->setSecretKey('KEY'); // TEST
    $formData = ['number' => '4111111111111111', 'cvv' => '333','expiryMonth' => 6, 'expiryYear' => 2016];
    $response = $gateway->purchase([
      'email'       => 'customer@customer.com.au',
      'description' => 'Widgets',
      'amount'      => '49.99',
      'currency'    => 'USD',
      'card_token'  => 'card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w',
      'testMode'    => true,
      'ip_address'  => '203.192.1.172',
      'card' => $formData


    ])->send();
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
    // payment was successful: update database
    print_r($response);
    } elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
        // redirect to offsite payment gateway
        $response->redirect();
    } else {
        // payment failed: display message to customer
        exit($response->getMessage());
    }
    echo $response->getMessage();
?>
```

And this is the error I get:
One or more parameters were missing or invalid

Any help appreciated:)

Comment: Judging by the documentation, you're missing the CVV in your `$formData` array: https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay

Comment: He Scrowler , thank for your reply, I've added in CVV. The code works find without it as I wasnt getting any messages from the server about CVV.

Comment: Are you getting that error from OmniPay or Pin Payments?

Comment: Error comes from Pin Payments

Comment: Try `var_dump($response->getData())` - can you see any more specific error messages in there?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:

```
$response = $gateway->purchase([
      'email'       => 'customer@customer.com.au',
      'description' => 'Widgets',
      'amount'      => '49.99',
      'currency'    => 'USD',
      'card_token'  => 'card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w',
      'testMode'    => true,
      'ip_address'  => '203.192.1.172',
      'card' => $formData


    ])->send();
```

Replace Above with the code below (note:->purchase(array( NOT ->purchase([

```
$response = $gateway->purchase(array(
      'email'       => 'customer@customer.com.au',
      'description' => 'Widgets',
      'amount'      => '49.99',
      'currency'    => 'USD',
      'card_token'  => 'card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w',
      'testMode'    => true,
      'ip_address'  => '203.192.1.172',
      'card' => $formData


    ))->send();
```

Comment: oh and also dont forget to add all billing fields to the card object.

Comment: Use var_dump($response) to get the full output. There is also a list of errors in the JSON returned by Pin, so you should see this output in the $response object.

Comment: If the only difference is you changed `[]` to `array()`, that's nothing to do with Omnipay - it just means you're running PHP 5.3 or lower, since the short array syntax was [introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error: "One or more parameters were missing or invalid"
was simply caused by not having two words for the card holder name when testing.